# Emulate gold letters in Inkscape

Tags: inkscape, texture

I would like to write with golden letters in Inkscape. I've found the Gold gradient, but no gold texture in the filters.

How can I do that?

Comment: See also: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rjFlxc5YPJk

Answer (score 8, accepted):

gold typically doesn't have texture. I assume you're asking how to make a surface look reflective like Gold. A tutorial on making chrome text (a popular tutorial in a lot of image editing software) should get you there. Just swap the greys of chrome for the yellows of gold:

http://inkscapetutorials.wordpress.com/2008/01/31/chrome-text-effect/

Comment: That sounds like an answer to my question, unfortunately the blog that contains the tutorial is restricted so I can't read it...

Comment: Corporate IT blocks it? If so, time to find a new gig. ;) Otherwise, google 'chrome text in inkscape' and you should find some other tutorials.

Comment: No, it's not blocked by any proxies, it's blogger that says I have to be invited to this blog in order to see it. That said, I found another method which says to use the "Chrome" filter in Inkscape. That's fine, but there's no "Gold" filter filter.

Comment: ah, the original blog that hosted that tutorial went away. I have updated the link on http://inkscapetutorials.wordpress.com to point to an archive.org backup of the tutorial.

Comment: Finally! An Inkscape tutorial site by someone who's actually good at art and design!