# How to make a gold plate in Inkscape?

Tags: inkscape, effects

I'm intending to recreate a square shiny gold plate. I've found in [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CDC3xqGPoUc) but I couldn't reproduce it as I don't know how to work with multiple gradients.

Does it exist a better guide on how to do it?. I've intended to use gradient tool in fill options in a square plate but the only thing which I got was a simple gradient whose background color was white, can someone help me with this?.

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. You can use the gradient tool to add stops to make any gradient you want. Maybe have a look at [this tutorial on youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=39mJPLl-nno) which shows how to make more complex gradients.

Comment: Your question is very akin to [this question](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/3293/emulate-gold-letters-in-inkscape), maybe you can try Inkscape [filters](http://tavmjong.free.fr/INKSCAPE/MANUAL/html/Filters-Preset.html) like *Glowing Metal* and similar.

Answer (score 1):

Hopefully you have done as already suggested by user Billy Kerr and learned how to make more complex gradients than one color to transparency.

What is a gold gradient? It's a cliche. One picks to a gradient colors which can occur in a photo taken from golden objects in an environment which doesn't add too much other colors. Polished gold reflects well like a mirror with yellowish cast so keeping the scene golden there cannot be much other colors reflected from the gold.

The next image has a photo of gold bars and a rectangle filled with 6  stop gradient, all stop colors are picked from the photo:

[image]

The rectangle doesn't look flat, it's like a piece of cylinder in an environment where the light is a mixture of white light and reflections from gold. Actually there's no other information available of the surface curvature. The impression "it's cylindrical" is only a result of numerous seen images which have had somehow resembling shading and we knew they were cylindrical.

The white highlight is an error. The photo is adjusted so that the brightest area would need brighter yellow than our RGB color system can make. It's clipped to white 255,255,255. People who adjust photos do often the same because it makes more contrast possible. The price is whitening the brightest colors.

The next image is a theoretical palette how different greyscale colors behave when the get successively reflected from gold:

[image]

The top line is pure white reflected 0...8 times from pure gold. The next lines are dimmer greys with same reflections.

Remember: Pure white in an image of gold is an error caused by the limitations of our RGB system. Dimmer greys on gold (except black) are impossible. Black = no light.

If you want to draw a flat rectangle with gold gradient the color differences cannot be wide. In the next image the start and stop colors are adjacent in the previous table:

[image]

It doesn't look polished. It's matt or the environment is featureless. A realistic polished flat surface in realistic environment could look for ex. like this:

[image]

If you are going to draw something more complex which should seem to be gold you are not aiming especially little. See this old case:

[Illustrator: How to create realistic reflective gold surface?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/120975/illustrator-how-to-create-realistic-reflective-gold-surface)

There few of us have tried to draw some gold ingots with different methods. Also 3D models are shown. I must admit that rendering a 3D model does it much easier if any realism is expected.

Comment: Interesting so in short terms the effect can be achieved by only playing with stop gradients?. As it is mentioned the illusion which I attempted to recreate was as it depicted on the video, which I believe it is made possible by using gradients, is this part am I getting right?. Can you add the steps of how did you made the mate plate over the picture which shown a polished gold picture displaying a photo cameraman?.

Comment: Not playing with stop gradients, but playing with gradient stops!!! In your linked video there's another cliche: Reflected sky and reflected ground on a little curved surface. It's actually "the making easily chrome-trick" it's only yellow and brown for gold. Chreme needs whire, greys and black. Mate over picture is a cropped photo. It has blending mode multiply so it blends with the underlying gold plate. The small reflection in the lens is a scaled copy and partially transparent to make it dimmer. It's actually bulged a little in a photo editor to make it appear to be on a curved lens.

Comment: Sorry about the name what I mean was [this](http://write.flossmanuals.net/inkscape/gradient-tool/#:~:text=Stops%20can%20be%20added%20by,the%20color%20of%20that%20stop.) So in short to make the mirror effect was made possible by combining the cameraman over the mate gold plate with blending mode multiply and as you mentioned the small camera in the reflexion is just a scaled copy?. Am I understanding you right?.

Comment: The plate in this case is flat and does not has any bents or waves, how can this be achieved?. Will it be adding a picture which has waves or bents?.

Comment: The colors which you had picked to make the gold plate were obtained from the theoretical palette so what colors did you used?. Just only from 0 to 8 in the first row?.

Comment: You understood right except the small reflection is distorted a little in Photoshop to make it appear to be on a convex surface. Inkscape hasn't photo editing tools, you need Photoshop, GIMP or other bitmap image editor, too. Inkscape can use bitmaps but they must be prepared elsewhere.

Comment: My flat plate has the leftmost yellow on the top line and column 2 on the 2nd color row. Bends and bumbs create in a complex way distorted image from the environment. See the image of the gold bars. The environment is other gold bars, the ceiling and the light. In drawings people make artificial reflections. Gold gradients are one way. Gradient meshes can make more complex patterns than linear and radial gradients.

Comment: So the bends and bumps are just seen because there's an environment from where there is reflection to notice it right? Otherwise it would look flat. So If I were to let's say try to add this effect I need a background which has waves?.I other words I have to go to Gimp and apply some distortion in the background image and put it behind the plate and apply the multiply blend?. Is this part right?

Comment: See this photo https://www.pngitem.com/pimgs/m/79-799369_golden-cup-png-image-gold-trophy-png-hd.png A complex piece of gold reflects lights, the ennviromment and also parts of itself. It can be difficult to decide which reflection is which. It makes room for artists. You can have an image of a flat plate of gold (=single color or very simple gradient) and blend it with multiply with distorted environment image. It can well make the impression of complex gold surface, If the distorted image is grayscale or has colors of multiple gold reflections there's no disturbances caused by green or blue.